# Why cobyla is using more iterations when objective function is less randomized?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quantum-computing

I am exploring [QAOA](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4028.pdf). To sum up, I mesure a parameterized quantum circuit, compute a function of the parameters based on the result and then optimize that function using cobyla. The optimization is classic, and it works so far.

I am using different simulators to simulate the work of the quantum circuits. The first runs a quantum circuit and returns a counts dictionary of measurement outcomes. The more shots it has, the closer the result to the result of the ideal circuit and is less randomazed. The second one simulate the circuit perfectly, the end result is not randomazed at all.

My observations show that the less there are randomization, the more iterations is takes for classic oplimization to be delivered. That is controintuitive.

The question is, why cobyla works that way?

I have read about the alrotithm, but have not found the answer.
I am using SciPy.

Comment: A flatter objective is often not easier. The noisy one may lead to quicker convergence to a local optimum.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, but why? I have a hypotesis, that for randomized function the algorithm "decides" that it can not improve the result earlier, but I don't know, how to prove it.

Comment: This is well-known behavior.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, is there anywhere, where I can read about this behavior? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is written down somewhere. But it makes sense if you create a lot of extra local optima by introducing noise, the algorithm will likely converge quickly to one of those. It can stop early because it cannot improve things anymore.